# How to compare two dates in moment JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have two inputs, one is a date, the second is a time. I need to check if that date and time is in the past or not.

I'm currently residing in Toronto,

My Date input is `8/15/2019`
My Time input is `12:00`

The issue I face is that when I grab the current date (right now it's 11:00 am. 8/15/2019) the time I actually get is `19:00` which makes the entire comparison incorrect.

What I tried

```
var startDateString = moment("8/15/2019" + " " + 12:00, "MM/DD"YYYY" + " HH:mm", true).format();
```

produces

```
`2019-08-15T12:00:00+04:00`
```

but current date in a string format is quite different.

```
var now = moment().format();
```

produces

```
`2019-08-15T19:00:00+04:00`
```

I was thinking it should have created a value of `2019-08-15T11:00:00+04:00`

If I can get some tips or assistance on how to correct compare dates, would be greatly appreciated. Maybe I have to offset current moment()?

Comment: Remember to actually set the timezone if you don't want things in UTC

Answer (score 1):

You *could* offset the time yourself, but that's unnecessary since you're already using Moment. Moment has an add-on library called [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/), which allows you to set the timezone for a date and convert between different time zones almost effortlessly.

Try including Moment Timezone (and the associated [10-year data](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.26/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js)) in your environment, then calling:

```
var startDateString = moment.tz("8/15/2019" + " " + "12:00", "MM/DD/YYYY" + " HH:mm", "America/New_York").format();
```

You can also operate on the time to convert it between different time zones like so:

```
let startDate = moment.tz("8/15/2019" + " " + "12:00", "MM/DD/YYYY" + " HH:mm", "America/New_York");
let la_startDate = startDate.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
let la_startDateString = la_startDate.format();
```